# How do I get just the first quartile from a column

Tags: r, statistics

I have a dataframes with a column called Means. I want to get just the first quartile from this column. I know I can use quartile (df) or summary (df) but this gives me all the quartiles. How do I get just the first?

Comment: See function `quantile` and its `probs` argument.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You could try this:

```
#sample data
Means <- runif(100)

#and this is how you get the first quartile
> summary(Means)[2]
1st Qu. 
 0.2325
```

Or using function `quantile` as per Pascal's comment:

```
> quantile(Means, 0.25)
      25% 
0.2324663
```

Comment: Note that you can always use a character reference as well: `summary(Means)[["1st Qu."]]`.

Answer (score 0):

To get just the value of the first quartile, you can do this:

```
> quantile(Means)[["25%"]]
[1] 0.2209037
```